# Suppressing parameter values from Python Window when running script in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, parameters

When I run a python script in ArcGIS Desktop 10.1 the values from the parameters will be written to the Python Window (marked with red in the picture below).

Does anybody know if it is possible to remove the parameter values or the other lines like the time stamp?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can turn these off.  All tools report the parameters.  However, you might want to try running your script tool in the background.

In the properties dialog box, untick the option to "Always run in foreground".

[image]